# How to hide Layout content in activity of ViewPager and tabs when I scroll though list view in fragment?

Tags: android

Condition:When I  scroll through list in  fragment of  viewpager, the  layout of  activity and tab  should be hidden

Can  anyone answer ?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
linearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: try to  understand the question. Its fragment  of  viewpager